# Determine if notification banner or notification in center was tapped to launch the app when app is background state

Tags: ios, push-notification

I have checked many threads and [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH103-SW4) for determining whether app is launched on tap of the notification.
I want to handle push notification only if user taps on notification.
I am not able to figure out reason of `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:` being called.
How can check if this method was called on tap of notification or direct from push when app is background.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is few steps for push Notification

1). When you app is killed, neither active nor in background. In that case `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will called when you receive any notification.

2). When your app is active or in background, in that case `didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler**` will called. You have to identify application state here as below.

```
if ( application.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive ) {  
    // app was already in the foreground
}
else {
    // app was just brought from background to foreground
}
```

Comment: The fact is that this method is called when we receive push notification when app is in background and user have not tapped on notification.
I want to differentiate between them. I want to Identify user's tap on notification banner.
When app is killed we can identify user's tap as didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler is called with inactive state but that is not the case for background state.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {
    //No Need to store the push notification if it is in active or in closed state we can directly navigate to the screens

    NSLog(@"notification didReceive method called");

    if([app applicationState] == UIApplicationStateInactive) {
        //If the application state was inactive, this means the user pressed     an action button
        //Handle the code after push notification received  
    }
    else if ([app applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        //Application is in Active state handle the push notification here
    }
}
```